# Set a new socket io connection per user

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io, mern

I'm using socket io in my MERN stack application to communicate between the client and server. Basically, I'm listening for changes in my mongodb cluster, and communicating those changes to the client with socketio emit function. The problem is that data communicated back to the client is specific to certain users, but the emit function "sends" those details to all users on the app. It seems all users are on the same socket client connection, or are at least recognised by the server as the same client connection. How can I make sure this inter-server-client communication with socketio is specific for each user.

**express & socket io server:**

```
const app = express();

app.use(cors({
  origin: CLIENT_ORIGIN
}));

//body parser middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

//Database config
const db = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
// console.log(db);

//connect to MongoDB database
mongoose
.connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    // useCreateIndex: true
})
.then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB...");

    // change streams go here
    // const changeStream = Users.collection.watch();
    // changeStream.on('change', next => {
    //     console.log(next);
    // })
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

// Express session
app.use(
    session({
      secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET+'',
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: true
    })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


//Server routes
//add server route that allows "home landing path"
app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));
app.use('/api/tags', require('./routes/api/tags'));
app.use('/api/comments', require('./routes/api/comments'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/reactions', require('./routes/api/reactions'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/landing'));



//Serve static folder if in production

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    app.enable('trust proxy');

    // Catch all to handle all other requests that come into the app. 
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
  }





const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port: ", PORT)
});


const io = socket.listen(server);


io.origins(CLIENT_ORIGIN);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log("server socket connection on...");

  socket.connected ? console.log('client server linked') : socket.emit('restartListen');

  //listen for changes/inserts/deletes in all posts
  socket.on('listenForPosts', (schoolId) => {
    console.log('listening for posts...');

    const pipeline = {
      $match: {
        'fullDocument.institution': schoolId
      }
    }

    const changeStream = Post.collection.watch(pipeline);

    changeStream.on('change', next => {
      switch(next.operationType) {
        case 'insert':
          console.log('an insert happened...');

          socket.emit('insert', {
            type: 'insert',
            msg: 'New question available',
            newPost: next.fullDocument
          });
          break;

        case 'update':
          console.log('an update happened...');

          socket.emit('update', {
            type: 'update',
            postId: next.documentKey._id,
            updateInfo: next.updateDescription.updatedFields,
            msg: "Question has been updated."
          });
          break;

        case 'delete':
          console.log('a delete happened...');

          socket.emit('delete', {
            type: 'delete',
            deletedId: next.documentKey._id,
            msg: 'Question has been deleted.'
          });
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    });

  });

  socket.on('stopListenForPosts', () => {
    changeStream.close();
    setTimeout(() => {
      socket.disconnect(true);
    }, 3000)
  });

})
```

**clint-side:**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io();

socket.connected ? console.log('Client Socket connected') : socket.connect();

socket.on('insert', (data) => {
     this.props.actions.postActions.doSocketInsert(data);
});

socket.on('update', (data) => {
     // console.log(data);
    this.props.actions.postActions.doSocketUpdate(data);
});

socket.on('delete', (data) => {
     this.props.actions.postActions.doSocketDelete(data);
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
     this.listen(socket);
});

socket.on('restartListen', () => {
    socket.connect();
    this.listen(socket);
});
```

**I was thinking maybe having each client join a room and emit the changes to that specific socket room?**

Comment: Socket.io automatically connects each user to a room with their id on connection.  You could emit a message to that room and it will only send to the one user.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this issue, you need to keep data about connected users with the socket. In order to perform that you can just create an array in memory and keep the user information in there. (connected user's user_id and socket_id).

Here is how you can store it.

```
let users = [];

socket.on('insert', data => {
  let found = false;
  users.forEach(element => {
    if (element.user._id === data.user._id) {
      found = true;
    }
  });
  if (!found) {
    users.push({ socket_id: socket.id, user: data.user });
  }
  console.log('-------Logged In Users--------');
  console.log(users);

  // do your other stuff here
});
```

Then after you need to parse the user_id with every message which you need to broadcast with the particular user. Then after, in the `listen` function you can check for the user's array which we have created in memory and find that particular socket_id related to the particular user and you can emit the message only for that user likes bellow.

```
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if(user._id === data.user._id){
        io.to(users[i].socket_id).emit('chat_message', obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looping through all connected users doesn't seem like the most efficient idea; there must be another way. Perhaps a socket.io function that inherently works as desired?

Answer (score 0):

You put this:

```
changeStream.on('change', ...)
```

inside of:

```
io.on('connection', ...)
```

That means that every single socket is listening for the `changeStream.on('change', ...)` so anything that happens on the `changeStream` will be sent out to every single socket.  It's even worse than that, in that it will even try to send it to all the previously connected sockets that are no longer connected (that will fail, but still the wrong thing to do).

So, I don't know exactly what you're trying to do here, but you usually don't want to be starting a separate listener for some outside resource for every single newly connected socket.

Comment: I'm basically trying to create a notification system per user. So when the changeStream picks up changes in the database those documents are tagged with the user whom the changes concern, and I'll use socket.io to communicate those changes to the frontend. But for some reason, all logged in users are being notified of all changes.

Comment: is there a way to achieve what I wrote in the comment above without having changeStream in the io.on() ? Thanks.